# UI-Router controller isn't working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to using UI-Router, and I'm struggling to get this controller working. The view loads, but the function doesn't trigger on ng-click. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awmiklovic/chmm3oks/4/)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('dashboardCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope){
        $scope.testFunction = function(){
            console.log('test');
        }
     }
]);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("dashboard", {
        url: "#",
        templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
        controller: "dashboardCtrl"
      });
});
```

View

```
<body ng-app="app">
<nav> 
    <a ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</nav>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

<script type = "text/ng-template" id = "dashboard.html">
      <button ng-click="testfunction()">Click</button>
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think `url: "#"` is a valid route URL. If you're trying to target the root path, just use `url: ""`

Comment: Also, your function is `testFunction` (capital "F") but your template is calling `testfunction` ~ https://jsfiddle.net/chmm3oks/10/

Comment: Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Thanks Phil, but I tried implementing this suggestion and it caused the router view to break. In the original fiddle, the view routing works, but the controller doesn't.

Comment: Ah! Thanks Phil, the typo was the issue!

Comment: Also, I think I'm understanding it a bit better now. Changing the "#" to "" causes it to load the view by default, so the router view is not broken. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `testfunction` in your template not working because there no function in controller called `testfunction`. In controller you specified it as `testFunction`. Note the capital letter 'F' in it. It will work if you change it. but, please not that `url: "#"` is not valid URL